# The type variable is ambiguous in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

**This is the original question:**

Modify the result of problem 10 in such a way that if an element has no duplicates it is simply copied into the result list. Only elements with duplicates are transferred as (N E) lists.

Example:

```
* (encode-modified '(a a a a b c c a a d e e e e))
((4 A) B (2 C) (2 A) D (4 E))
```

Example in Haskell:

```
ghci> encodeModified "aaaabccaadeeee"
[Multiple 4 'a',Single 'b',Multiple 2 'c',
Multiple 2 'a',Single 'd',Multiple 4 'e']
```

**This is my solution:**

```
import Data.List

data Encode a = Single a | Multiple Int a deriving (Show)

encodeModified :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [Encode a]
encodeModified xs = [y | x <- group xs, let y = if (length x) == 1   then Single (head x) else Multiple (length x) (head x)]

encodeModified' = map (\xs -> if (length xs == 1) then Single (head xs) else Multiple (length xs) (head xs)) . group
```

My GHCI is 7.10.3, when I execute :l xx.hs, it gives me:

```
No instance for (Eq a0) arising from a use of ‘group’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      encodeModified' :: [a0] -> [Encode a0] (bound at 11.hs:8:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance (Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (Either a b)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
      instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Eq (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
      instance (GHC.Arr.Ix i, Eq e) => Eq (GHC.Arr.Array i e)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Arr’
      ...plus 27 others
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘group’
    In the expression:
      map
        (\ xs
           -> if (length xs == 1) then
                  Single (head xs)
              else
                  Multiple (length xs) (head xs))
      . group
    In an equation for ‘encodeModified'’:
        encodeModified'
          = map
              (\ xs
                 -> if (length xs == 1) then
                        Single (head xs)
                    else
                        Multiple (length xs) (head xs))
            . group
```

I can't figure out what's the error by its feedback and I didn't find anything wrong with my method, if someone can help me? thanks.

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/oiDu42 What version of GHC are you using?

Comment: @ErikR I'm using 7.10.3

Comment: Also verified to work with 7.10.3. Create an input file to just those six lines and check.

Comment: @ErikR yeah I saw it in ideone.com, I got this error when I try to execute :l xx.hs, I don't know if there are something to do with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code here includes an `Eq a` constraint in the type of `encodeModified`, but from the error you posted, I can see that the type you actually have in your file for `encodeModified'` (note the prime!) does not have that constraint. Add the constraint and you should be good to go.

In the future, it is polite to post the code you are *actually* having a problem with.

Comment: Yeah you're right, and I posted the completed code, I didn't do it because I don't want to confuse others. And why here I have to add constraints on encodeModified', it shouldn't inherit from encodeModified? or I misunderstand something here? thanks

Comment: @wwayne What do you mean by "inherit"? Certainly there is no inheritance in the OO sense in Haskell.

Comment: My bad, I re-check what ' is in Haskell, it doesn't have special meaning, I misunderstood of it. Anyway, thanks for your patience and answer.